# Can I use 'quiet' as a verb in BrE?

Tags: parts-of-speech

Can I use the word 'quiet' as a verb in BrE (as opposed to N. American)? If I can, how is it conjugated?

The phrase I am looking to write is, "I wish to quiet my mind".

Should it be 'quieten'? That sounds incorrect.

Many thanks

Comment: And someone should coin *enquiet*, *bequiet*,...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use either *quieten* or *quiet* in BrE (British English), whereas *quiet* would usually be used in AmE (American English).

First, *quieten* and *quiet* are two distinct verbs. *Quieten* is a later invention: the Oxford English Dictionary gives an example from 1759. It is formed from the adjective *quiet* plus the suffix *-en*, which creates a verb from an adjective and means, more or less, to make quiet. (Other formations with *-en* include *moisten*, *harden*, and *darken*.) *[Quieten](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quieten)* is chiefly British, as Merriam-Webster points out, and is regular in conjugation - quietened, quietening, and so on.

*Quiet* as a verb comes from Middle English. It is [regular in formation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quiet): quiet, quieted, and quieting. The word is largely interchangeable with *quieten*, and its usage is broad. Only two meanings are marked as dialect-specific in the OED:

> 3. intransitive. Now chiefly N. Amer. To become quiet; to quieten. Frequently with down.
> 4. transitive. Chiefly Law (U.S. in later use). To settle or establish the fact of ownership of (a title, etc.); to settle or establish (a person, company, etc.) in quiet enjoyment or possession of land or property (chiefly in passive).

The other meanings of *quiet* (to calm or subdue, to make quiet) are available to everyone.

So yes, if you wish to quiet your mind on this question, you may.